# Python Turtle, White space between obejct

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Can anyone tell me, why there is a white space between the ground and the wall? I cant find the mistakte.
First it worked, but it seems like I changed amything and no i dont the what I did wrong. Thanks for helping!

Heres the code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import random
from random import randint

screen = Screen ()
screen.setup (1920, 1080, 0, 0)


t = Turtle ()
t.color ("red")
t.speed (0)

s = Turtle()
s.color("black")
s.speed(0)

# Ego-Perspektive

t.up ()
t.goto (-950, -450)
t.down ()

t.color ("#DFCBAF")
t.begin_fill ()
t.goto(950,-450)
t.goto(999.01,-0.99)
t.goto(-400.99,-0.99)
t.goto(-950,-450)
t.end_fill()

t.color ("#d28c5b")
t.begin_fill ()
t.up ()
t.goto (-950, -450)
t.down ()
t.goto(-950,510)
t.goto(670,510)
t.goto(670,-1)
t.goto(-498.5,-1)
t.goto(-950,-450)
t.end_fill ()

t.color ("black")
t.goto(-950,510)
t.goto(670,510)
t.goto(670,-1)
t.goto(-498.5,-1)
t.goto(-950,-450)
t.up()
t.goto(-498.5,-1)
t.down()
t.setheading(90)
t.forward(500)

t.up()
t.goto(-415,60)
t.down()
t.setheading(0)
t.color("#000c1a")
t.begin_fill()
for x in range(2):
    t.forward(1000)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(290)
    t.left(90)
t.end_fill()

t.up()
t.goto(-415,60)
t.down()
t.setheading(0)
t.color("black")
t.width(5)
for x in range(2):
    t.forward(1000)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(290)
    t.left(90)
t.up()
t.goto(85,60)
t.down()
t.setheading(90)
t.forward(290)


def himmel1():
    s.up()
    s.goto(random.randint(-400,570),random.randint(100,360))
    s.down()
    s.dot(5, "#DFE6FF")

def himmel2():
    s.up()
    s.goto(random.randint(-400,570),random.randint(100,350))
    s.down()
    s.dot(5, "#757196")

def himmel3():
    s.up()
    s.goto(random.randint(-400,570),random.randint(100,350))
    s.down()
    s.dot(5, "#CED5FF")

def himmel4():
    s.up()
    s.goto(random.randint(-400,570),random.randint(100,350))
    s.down()


def stern():
    links  = 144
    vorne = 12
    s.color("yellow")
    s.begin_fill()
    for x in range(1):
        s.begin_fill()
        s.up()
        s.goto(random.randint(-400,570),random.randint(100,350))
        s.down()
        for x in range(5):
            s.forward(vorne)
            s.left(links)
        s.end_fill()
    
for x in range(17):
    himmel1()
    himmel3()
    himmel2()
    himmel3()

for i in range(10):
    stern()
```

This text is only here because the website tells me izs to much code and to less text so just ignore this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change all occurrences of `-498.5` to `-400`. Then the wall and the floor will be aligned.

For such drawings, you can be easily confused by the coordinates of the points. It can get really complicated to debug and change the code. You might want to store the coordinates of the points in some variables such that you won't get lost. In your case, the coordinate point (-400, -1) is miswritten as (-498.5, -1) when you are drawing the wall.